# clickOnce publish not deploying my app.exe.config

Tags: clickonce, config

ClickOnce is not deploying my app.exe.config file in wpf project. I have the build action to "none" and copy to directory with "Copy always".

Also in the properties of the project, publish, application files, I can't my config file in the list.

Any hints?

Comment: I found the trick, I have to set the build action of the config file to "content" then it work just fine.

On other thread found here (stackOverflow), it recommend to set the build action to none, But it's doesn't work for me.

Comment: Someone gave me a -1 rating for no reason. If that's a stupid question he could've just answer simply. I wasted hours before finding it. I'm a bit fustrated of this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can also copy the config to the content subfolder by hand (which I did until I noticed your update above (thanks)).  But I had to rename from "App.config" to ."exe.config.deploy"

Answer (score 0):

Set the build action of the config file (App.config) to "none" and "copy anyway"  then it works.